# Webpack / Angular CLI / Proxy forwarding

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli, webpack-dev-server, http-proxy-middleware

I need to setup a proxy within AngularCLI / Webpack env to forward requests from `http://localhost:4200/rest` to `https://someserver.com/somepath/rest`

For one, the endpoint is a https and not a http.

Secondly, the request url could be `http://localhost:4200/rest/foo` or `...:4200/rest/bar` and all and any of the paths coming after '/rest' need to be mapped to `https://someserver.com/somepath/rest/foo` or `...com/somepath/rest/bar`

The following proxy.conf.json doesn't seem to be configured properly:

```
"/rest": {
    "target": "https://someserver.com",
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "ws": true,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/rest/": "/somepath/rest/"
    },
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
```

The app is started with

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --live-reload --host 0.0.0.0
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should change your `pathRewrite`

```
 "/rest/": {
        "target": "https://someserver.com/somepath/rest/",
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "ws": true,
        "pathRewrite": {
          "^/rest/": "/"
        },
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug"
      }
```